# scrollIntoView with smooth behavior not working in chrome when raised by wheel event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, js-scrollintoview

It's a bit tricky to explain, so maybe the easiest way to understand the problem is to go to [the site web](https://antoine.duparay.fr) and compare the behavior between Firefox (working perfectly as expected) and chrome (scrollIntoView is not working).

Basically, I have a left column menu but I didn't wanted to put a position: fixed so it's a relative one with a float. So the scroll for the main content is with overflow-y on .

Now, I have a "welcome" image which takes all the screen height of the visitor. The behavior I created is when the visitor scroll down, it goes straight to the end of the image. And when the visitor is just below the image and scroll a bit up, it goes directly to the top of the image. Apart from that, the scroll in the text works ordinary.

Everything is working fine with Firefox but Chrome is not scrolling into view as expected. See the scroll.js file in the website linked above, console.log shows that chrome is catching the wheel event and entering scrollIntoView but doesn't scroll.

Is that a bug in chrome that I should report?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the `WheelEvent.deltaMode` value to know *how* the brwoser is reporting the wheel event:

> `WheelEvent.deltaMode`
>
> Read only
>
> Returns an unsigned long representing the unit of the delta values scroll amount. Permitted values are:
>
> `Constant        Value   Description`
>
> `DOM_DELTA_PIXEL  0x00    The delta values are specified in pixels.`
>
> `DOM_DELTA_LINE   0x01    The delta values are specified in lines.`
>
> `DOM_DELTA_PAGE   0x02    The delta values are specified in pages.`

A good library to standardize the wheel events across browsers is https://github.com/basilfx/normalize-wheel

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is the problem. If you check the console.log, chrome is entering the function as expected. The bug lies in the call to scrollIntoView with the behavior set to smooth.